# Python-like generators in bash

Tags: bash, buffer

I came up with a nice way of having generators in bash, just like in python:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
    # Main code. Notice that we are in main thread, which would not be the case if we used a pipe.
    ...
    IFS= read -d '' -r VALUE  # equivalent of "next()" in python
    ...
} < <(
    # string generator
    ...
    printf "%s\0" "$VALUE"  # equivalent of "yield" in python
    ...
)
```

A typical example of usage that I was working on is the following.
I want to have it this way because I want to keep the main loop concise.

```sh
LINK_NAME="$DIR/$(basename "$FILE")"
while [ -e "$LINK_NAME" ] && [ "$(readlink "$LINK_NAME")" != "$TARGET" ]; do
    IFS= read -d '' -r LINK_NAME
done < <(
    printf "%s\0" "$DIR/Link to $(basename "$FILE")"
    printf "%s\0" "$DIR/Another link to $(basename "$FILE")"
    declare -i COUNT=3
    while true; do
        case $COUNT in
            *1?) ORD="th";;
             *1) ORD="st";;
             *2) ORD="nd";;
             *3) ORD="rd";;
              *) ORD="th";;
        esac
        printf "%s\0" "$DIR/$COUNT$ORD link to $(basename "$FILE")"
        COUNT+=1
        
        echo "[generated $COUNT]" >&2  # Debug
        ((COUNT>=100)) && break        # safety break
    done
)
```

**Problem**: the generator generates (a lot) more values than necessary, and this becomes a problem when the main program is slow. I was hoping for the `printf` in the generator to halt until it's output is consumed, but it seems not to be the case.

I tried using `stdbuf -o0 printf ...` and `stdbuf -oL printf ...` (wasn't sure which one would be the more adapted here) like in
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe
but that didn't helped.
And I couldn't use `stdbuf` on the whole generator because, well, this is not a program with a path. And I don't want to create a separate file for the generator, it will ruin the conciseness of the thing.

How can I make the generator wait that the output is consumed before producing more values?

---

Update (thanks to @glennjackman comment): I could make it work, using two dirty function definitions, and the rest is pretty clean.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
yield() { read -r; printf "%s\0" "$*"; }
next() { local _N _P="$1[1]"; echo >&"${!_P}"; _P="$1[0]"; IFS= read -d '' -r ${2-_N} <&"${!_P}"; (($#<2)) && echo -n "$_N"; }

coproc generator (
    ...
    yield "$VALUE"
    ...
)
# Main code
...
VALUE="$(next generator)"
# or even
next generator VALUE
...
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of this. Why not use a regular loop? Why are you `read`ing your own output, instead of just setting a variable?

Comment: Why are you trying to torture bash to do this? I suspect you need `coproc`. Failing that, the two processes will have to communicate with signals (`kill` and `trap`)

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman, `coproc` is what I needed. But this is true that this is becoming convoluted. Yes for this relatively simple example a regular loop would have worked, but "generators" might come handy in other situations...